# Writing a c++ Client-Server program using winsock2

Tags: udp, winsock2

I am having some trouble with a UDP-based connection. 
In my program, I restrict the time allocated for data transfer between the transmitter and receiver (both of them are sending/receiving in a loop). 
When the time passes, I send a message from the transmitter that if the receiver receives and reads - the receiver knows not to wait for anymore packets so the program continues.

The problem I thought of was that because the connection is UDP, the message might not get to the receiver, and then the client will keep on waiting for messages, but no one is sending.

So what is the correct way to finish such a connection?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no connection to finish in UDP. There are only individual datagrams, which may arrive in or out of the correct order, zero or one or more than one time. If you want a connection, use TCP.

Comment: I understand what you are saying - maybe "finish the connection" aren't the right words, I am trying to understand how I can get the transmitter and receiver both to know they don't need to send/receive anymore.

Comment: You'll have to send something that tells the peer, and get an acknowledgment, something like the four-way TCP close handshake.